# Adding support for other bracket types VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to add <> for the command editor.action.selectToBracket. however, no matter if I put it in language default or elsewhere, it does not work. The reason I want this is because lots of things are defined between <> and having that quick select would make things super easy.
[bracketselection with custom lang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXL8o.png)
[bracketselection generic/global](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFWJQ.png)

If anyone has any idea what I could do please let me know.